# how to reference a model in another model using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I'm pretty new to node and mongoose, still learning a lot. Basically I am trying to create a forum page. I have a forumpost schema and I have recently added in a new field that I would like to show which user posted it. I have read other questions on this online and I was able to follow the code on there however mine is still not working. When i check my data in atlas it is still missing the new 'submitted by' field that I added. I have already deleted the 'collection' and have started over but it is still missing. Any help would be appreciated. Heres my models below as well as a screencap of how the data is being posted to the db.

```
**Post Form Schema** 

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    body: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
        required: true,
    },
    submittedBy: { *(this is where I would like to get the user who submitted the form)*
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'User',
    },
    extraInfo: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Other info goes here',
    }
})

const Post = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
module.exports = Post;
```

```
**Users Form Schema**

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

EDIT: heres my newpost route

```
const express = require('express');
const Post = require('../models/post');
const router = express.Router();
const {ensureAuthenticated} = require("../config/auth.js");

router.get('/', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.render('newPost')
})

router.post('/', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    const post = new Post(req.body);
    console.log(req.body)

    post.save()
    .then((result) => {
        res.redirect('/dashboard')
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
})

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, you validate if is authenticated with the "ensureAuthenticated" middleware (the user ID should be there) but when creating the "Post" you only do it with the body data.

It is something like this ( you should replace "userId" with your property name):

```
const post = new Post({ ...req.body, submittedBy: userId })
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! here's my routing for 'new post'

Comment: I edited the answer with the changes you told me!

Comment: you're a lifesaver, for some reason I thought it would automatically pull the user on submit, overlooked the fact that I would have to assign it. Thank you!!